# A set $A$ contains infinitely many terms of a real sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logic

What does this statement mean mathematically ?

"A real sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is contained in set $A$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$."

This is my mathematical statement

"A real sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is said to be contained in set $A$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if there exist a one to one correspondence from the set $\left\{n \in \mathbb{N} \textrm{ } | \textrm{ } x_n \in A \right\} $ to $\mathbb{N}$."

Is my statement a correct mathematical representation of the statement "A real sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is contained in set $A$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$." ?

If not, then what would be the correct mathematical definition for the former statement ?

Comment: I guess that by "one to one correspondence" you mean there is a bijection between that set and the naturals...Is this correct?

Comment: Does your first statement mean that $x_n \in A$ for infinite $n\in \mathbb N?$

Comment: Not quite: your definition doesn't work if the same value appears multiple times in the sequence. For example, the constant sequence $x_n = 1$ is 'contained in $[0,2]$ for infinitely many $n$' but fails your definition.

Comment: Yes @DonAntonio.

Comment: Yes @miracle173

Comment: Change $A \cap \left\{x_n \textrm{ } | \textrm{ } n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ to $\{n\in \mathbb{N}|x_n\in A\}$ for the reason given by realdonaldtrump

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is correct now. But to a mathematician, perhaps a more natural formalisation would be:

> For all $n\in\mathbb N$ there exists $m\in\mathbb N$ with $m\ge n$ and $x_m\in A$

This is about individual elements rather than correspondences between sets, which makes it easier to work with.